# How to sort objects on page load? Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a table, where a user can `sort` items by selected `values`, the problem is, that i'm using a vue `watcher`, and on page load it doens't seem to `sort` items by watched `value`, if I select the `value` manually, it works.

I tried to define the watched value of data object sort, `this.sort = 'created_at'` on the created method, didn't seem to help.

HTML:

```
 <select v-model="sort">
    <option value="date_installed" selected>Latest</option>
    <option value="status">Status</option>
 </select>

data: () => ({
  affiliates: {},
  filtered: {},
  sort: '',
}),
created() {
  this.sort = 'date_installed';

      axios.get('/dashboard/affiliates')
    .then(res => {
      let data = res.data;
      this.affiliates = data.affiliates.filter(obj => {
        return obj;
      });
      this.filtered = data.affiliates.filter(obj => {
        return obj;
      });
    })
},
watch: {
 sort: function (val) {
    return this.filtered = _.orderBy(this.affiliates, val, 'desc');
  },
},
```

How could I solve this problem and sort the table by created_at value immediately on page load?

Comment: I have to select a value from a select element manually to order items.
I want that the items would be sorted by default value 'created_at'

Comment: It's simple as it sounds, but at the moment stuck on trying. Is it clear what am I asking?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a watcher, use a computed property here:

```
watch: {
 sort: function (val) {
    return this.filtered = _.orderBy(this.affiliates, val, 'desc');
  },
```

like:

```
computed: {
 sorted: function () {
    return _.orderBy(this.affiliates, this.sort, 'desc');
  },
```

then use the value of this.sorted as you would with a normal property